# Python invalid syntax on scrapy pipeline for mysql

Tags: python, scrapy

I dont understand why i get an syntax error here... i dont find anything wrong and no spaces...

```
/pipelines.py", line 23
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The error here

and thats my code

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class AmazonMobileDetailsPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxx', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO items (name, price, imagelink) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (item['mobile_name'].encode('utf-8'), item['mobile_price'].encode('utf-8'), item['mobile_imagelink'].encode('utf-8')))            
            self.conn.commit()            
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
        return item
```

Comment: should be `MySQLdb.Error as e` not a comma

Comment: Google "python try except" to find what the correct syntax. Hint: python doesn't use a comma in this context.

Comment: You are trying to run Python 2 code with Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
```

Have a look at the [official docmentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Now i get that: ```print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

The arrow shows on " after %s

Comment: @Scholli Are you using Python 2.7? For Python 3.x use `print("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

You are using code written for Python 2 but running Python 3. Both the comma in an `except` clause and the `print` without parentheses are no longer valid.

You should find a more up-to-date documentation to follow when writing your code.